# Undefined property: stdClass::$id

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm make a CRUD with anguarjs. but update error. the error is :

> Undefined property: stdClass::$id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crud_login\data\update.php

anyone can help me? I'm new in angularjs

controller :

```
$scope.edit = function(index){
        //var index = getSelectedIndex($index);
        $scope.listData.nama = $scope.dataList[index].nama;
        $scope.listData.alamat = $scope.dataList[index].alamat;
    }
$scope.update = function(){
        $http.post(
            'data/update.php',
            {
                id: $scope.idChanged,
                data: $scope.listData
            }
        ).success(function(data){
            alert(data);
            $scope.getData();
            $scope.aksi = "add";
        }).error(function(){
            alert("Gagal mengubah data");
        });
    };
```

update.php :

```
<?php

    include 'koneksi.php';

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $dataObjek = json_decode($postdata);

    $id = $dataObjek->id;
    $nama = $dataObjek->data->nama;
    $alamat = $dataObjek->data->alamat;

    $query = "update listdata set nama = '{$nama}',alamat='{$alamat}' where id = {$id} ";

    $result = mysqli_query($koneksi,$query);

    $respon = "";
    if($result){
        $respon = "Berhasil menyimpan data";
    }else{
        $respon = "Gagal menyimpan data";
    }

    echo $respon;

?>
```

view :

```
    <h2 align="center">Edit Data</h2>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="nama">Nama:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="listData.nama">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="alamat">Alamat:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="listData.alamat">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="update()">Update</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `print_r($dataObjek)` chk this and share the result

Comment: In your query  where id = {$id}, can you please remove braces {} from it? and let me know.

Comment: @JigarPrajapati: this is not an issue, issue in property scope

Comment: @Faizah Pratiwi : can you please share a view template ?

Comment: when i check with print_r($dataObjek) the output is stdClass Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

)

Comment: so it means you dont have anything in $dataObjek, only `data` available but still empty

Comment: $dataObjek is empty, so you should check if your variable contains any data before executing your update query.

Comment: dont understand, u r using ajax, than y need `$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");`